# Rails, RabbitMQ and Sidekiq Architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq, microservices, sidekiq

I have a very trivial - I guess - situation, and several implementation choices. I have a Rails app (call it Core) that, upon user request, crawls data from the internet. The crawler doesn't have any business logic - at least for now - however fetching and persisting data is a job that takes time and I would'n want it to be blocking.

I've considered different architectures, however I am not sure which one will work the best when things scale up. Options:

1. Sidekiq: Every time a user requests data to be crawled, a background job in Sidekiq gets born and crawls data, persists them and job is done. Possible drawback here is that I will not pay for Sidekiq Pro edition and I am not sure whether the OSS version will suit my needs.
2. RabbitMQ: Develop a microservice, let's call it Fetcher, in Rails again, which will consume from RabbitMQ and fetch and persist data. I haven't not understood whether in this case I need background processing as well, so again Sidekiq (or Sneakers). If I do, what's the advantage of using a message broker (in this case) instead of having Sidekiq do the background processing in the same application?

Comment: You don't need to develop a separate microservice. 
You will be able to start your rails app as a "worker" in addition to your rails server.
Both Sidekiq and Sneakers provide a way to create job/worker classes that execute inside these "worker" processes.

Comment: The difference between Sneakers and Sidekiq is the backend in which they store messages to process. Sidekiq uses redis and Sneakers uses RabbitMQ. Sidekiq is more polished and is easier to use imo. Also you can reuse Redis for sessions storage etc. RabbitMQ though will let you queue up more jobs and process them faster because it can store job messages on disk and it's concurrent. It's also harder to set up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your architectural proposal is moving in the right direction.

- **Sidekiq OSS**: I truly belive that sidekiq OSS version will properly fit your needs. It has several features to support background jobs supported by Redis. I recommend that you to read [its documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki) to understand best practices and what should be avoided.
- **Microservices** is a [good architectural choice to achieve scalability](http://microservices.io/articles/scalecube.html) as it promotes functional decomposition and you can make specific decisions on how to scale each service individually. However, it will increase the complexity of your system in several ways, requiring you to highly automate your infrastructure. I suggest you to [read this arcitle](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-trade-offs.html) from Martin Fowler webpage. He discusses the trade-offs related to the adoption of micro-services.
- The advantanges of using **RabbitMQ** are to enable reliable asynchronous communication between multiple services, support scalability, and provide flexible means for communication such as pub/sub and RPC. If you keep the idea of microservices this is the right way to go. Otherwise, a monolithic Rails application will only require the use of the sidekiq.
- If you use RabbitMQ, you should use a proper [RabbitMQ client](https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html). For ruby, use [Bunny](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny) in both the publisher and the consumer services since it will provide a good API to [publish data on RabbitMQ](http://rubybunny.info/articles/exchanges.html) and will also [support background processing for receiving data](http://rubybunny.info/articles/queues.html). Thus, there is no need to use sidekiq to consume data in Fetcher service.
- As you are going to do asynchronous processing, your clients will not know the final result of their request with your HTTP responses. So it would be interesting to use a mechanism that allows your application to notify them when your app finish processing the tasks asynchronously (i.e., through a status update on the user page). For this goal you could use **Websockets**, which is already supported in Rails through Action Cable.

My final tip is: if you're still prototyping your application and experimenting with ideas, I suggest you follow the path of monolithic architecture and be more concerned with validating your proposal. But if you already have a well-structured proposal and know the expected demand for the application, the microservice architecture can be a good choice to develop a scalable and reliable system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed reply and all the pointers Arthur. A minor follow up here: Bunny does indeed support consumers for RabbitMQ, but I haven't found examples where it can fan out several threads like Sidekiq does. I mean, will I have to implement the background processing myself if I go the Bunny way? Almost all examples I've seen use bunny with Sneakers workers. Let's say Fetcher rails app consumes data from RabbitMQ, so it gets a message, and starts processing. In my understanding, it cannot get another message until it finishes with the first one, am I missing something?

Comment: Take a look on this [link](http://rubybunny.info/articles/concurrency.html).  It explores some concurrency aspects of Bunny. More precisely, the section Consumer Work Pools defines how to set thread pool size. Therefore, Bunny will create threads for consumers which may not will not block your main thread by default (see _block_ parameter). IMO, that is the reason for not using sidekiq. For more details, take a look on the implementation of the [**subscribe method** of Bunny's Queue class](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny/blob/master/lib/bunny/queue.rb).

Comment: Besides, if you may [have competing consumers](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) to scale the reading of your queues. Puma, for example, will start concurrent processes and threads to your application, which will consequently add competing consumers for your app.